# Configuring authentication with Google Maps Engine driver from GDAL?

Tags: gdal, google-maps-engine

I'm using last **GDAL from trunk**, and trying to read from **Google Maps Engine (GME)** vía [GME driver](http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/GMEDriver)

I already exported

```
GME_API_KEY: My API Key, for the app I registered
GOA2_CLIENT_ID:  Generated with the "ClientID for installed applications" option in Google OAauth2 API Console
GOA2_CLIENT_SECRET: Idem
```

Also ran **swig/python/scripts/gdal_auth.py** script this way:

```
python swig/python/scripts/gdal_auth.py -s gme
```

Obtaining a **GME_REFRESH_TOKEN**, valid for 1 hour.

The problem is **I'm getting a HTTP 401 error (Invalid credentials)** with requests like this one

```
ogrinfo "GME:tables={my_table_id}"
```

Debugging, I've found **the Authorization: Bearer HTTP header is incorrect**. But I've used the same client id and client secret for [QGIS GME plugin](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/GoogleMapsEngineConnector/) and it works.

What should I do to make the driver work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already fixed it. I had to follow these steps:

- Define GOA2_CLIENT_ID, GOA2_CLIENT_SECRET, GME_APIKEY
- Define GME_REFRESH_TOKEN, which allow the app to refresh the token

No problem, so far. Just followed the [wiki page](http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/GMEDriver)

- Define GME_AUTH (or provide 'auth' in the query string). This is not specified in the wiki page, but can be found [here](https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/trunk/gdal/ogr/ogrsf_frmts/gme/ogrgmedatasource.cpp#L140):

The steps to get those environment vars are:

- GOA2_CLIENT_ID, GOA2_CLIENT_SECRET, GME_APIKEY --> from Google API console
- GME_AUTH, GME_REFRESH_TOKEN --> execute gdal_auth.py. Also stated in the wiki page. Just use the interactive option.

gdal_auth.py -s gme